# how to search a segmented route?

Tags: here-api

im implementing HERE route search in my app, i have at most 9 destinations as stops along the route, my problem is that in these routes could be vehicle change (like, car to plane), of course, in those case i don´t expect to have a route, but for performance reasons and to avoid sending 10 route request, im sending all the waypoints, even the unneeded, the problem in this case is of there is a section of all the route with no route found, then i get a WebExcepion with no response. There is any option i could enable to get the legs with maneuvers when there is one, and a error in the legs without route? i want to avoid sending several requests for each route.

Answer (score 0):

waypoints, legs, summary are the default attributes for a route. this can't be disable even if there is no route between the two waypoints. However the response can be optimised for legs attributes, which is not needed in your case. this needs to be handled during rendering at UI side to avoid displaying route if there isn't any route,